# Iterate models without hardcoding it with R

Tags: r, automation, hardcode

I have this code

```
#  [1] "X6"  "X5"  "X7"  "X4"  "X3"  "X8"  "X19" "X9"  "X10" "X16"    
formula = result ~ X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X16+X19
full_magnetude_model = glm.fit <- glm(formula, data = train)
full_magnetude_predict = predict(full_magnetude_model, newdata=test)

# Comparing results
full_magnetude_results <- ifelse(full_magnetude_predict > 0.5, 1, 0)
true_results = test$result

# results
table(full_magnetude_results,true_results)
```

It is working properly but the results are functuating for different formulas and I need do the same for:

```
#  [1] "X6"  "X5"  "X7"  "X4"  "X3"  "X8"  "X19" "X9"  "X10" "X16"    
#  [1] "X6"  "X5"  "X7"  "X4"  "X3"  "X8"  "X19" "X9"  "X10"    
#  [1] "X6"  "X5"  "X7"  "X4"  "X3"  "X8"  "X19" "X9"      
#  [1] "X6"  "X5"  "X7"  "X4"  "X3"  "X8"  "X19"     
#  [1] "X6"  "X5"  "X7"  "X4"  "X3"  "X8"
```

and so on, I can manualy do this but is there are smart way to do it?

**Update**

full code:
https://github.com/martin-varbanov96/fmi_summer_2018/blob/master/fmi_6ti_sem/Pril_stat/project/main.R

the idea is to make a list of formulas and apply my code for each element of the list

Comment: I assume fitting formulas into a list and using `lapply` with your code on each of them should end up a with a list of table results looking like what you're after (but the overall question is above my head, so I may overlook something)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I think I can achieve the same by making a list of formulas and wrapping my code over a for loop for each formula

Comment: Let's see if I get it right: the first code block in your question is the exemple for 1 formula, and you'd want 5 tables beings the results for the 5 formulas in your second code block, right ?

Comment: yes that is correct, I've been thinking of doing something like formulas = [formula1, formula2.....] and looping for the array, using the formulas to do the same code

Comment: Check `list` and `lapply`, this should do the trick. I can't really write an answer without dummy data to fill in

Comment: BTW your `full_magnetude_results <- ifelse(full_magnetude_predict > 0.5, 1, 0)` would be better without the ifelse, ust use `full_magnetude_results <- full_magnetude_predict > 0.5`to get a TRUE/FALSE vector. (using integers in place of booleans whithout a reason is usually a bad practice IMHO)

Comment: I've made an update, that last recommendation is not very good, because I'd also have to change my test set which is in {0,1}

Comment: you can get all the formulas:`Reduce(function(x,y)reformulate(attr(drop.terms(terms(x),y),"term.labels"),"results"),init = formula,10:7,accumulate = T)` But still you will have to loop over them. Instead of doing this, you can use the `update` function, which will just drop one variable and give you the results when that variable is dropped. That will be the better option

Comment: Then at worst: `as.integer(full_magnetude_predict > 0.5)` sounds less complex than ifelse

Comment: `lapply(1:4,function(x)reformulate(head(a,-x),"results"))` where `a` is a vector of all the variables, ie `a=c("X3","X4",....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a full answer but this should give an idea:

```
terms=c("X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X16", 
        "X19")

lapply(10:6,function(x) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste("result ~ ", paste0(terms[1:x],collapse="+")))
  formula
})
```

Gives:

```
[[1]]
result ~ X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X16 + X19
<environment: 0x0000000016fbec50>

[[2]]
result ~ X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X16
<environment: 0x0000000016fc29a0>

[[3]]
result ~ X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10
<environment: 0x00000000170f44b0>

[[4]]
result ~ X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9
<environment: 0x00000000170f8a98>

[[5]]
result ~ X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8
<environment: 0x00000000170fd1d0>
```

Lapply will iterate as much as the range (10 to 6) passing that to the anonymous function, this x will be used to select the needed terms.

The idea is to build your formulas from the needed terms, here removing one each time, pasting them as show in `?as.formula` documentation and getting the formula, the rest of your code can be used as is, the resulting list will contain tables instead of the formulas in this example.